# Display double array in picturebox

Tags: c#, bitmap, rgb, picturebox, brightness

I need to display this array of double in picture box in C#

```
double[,] Y1 = new double[width, height];//not empty array contain brightness from RGB
 R = new byte [width, height];
 G = new byte [width, height];
 B = new byte [width, height];

Bitmap bmp4 = new Bitmap(width, height);    


for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        Y1[x, y] = (0.39 * R[x,y]) + (0.59 * G[x,y]) + (0.12 * B[x,y]);
        Int32 zz = Convert.ToInt32(Y1[x, y]);

        bmp4.SetPixel(x, y, zz);
    }
}    

pictureBox6.Image=bmp4;
```

I use this code for display but not work is there other method for display array of 
`double(Brightness)` in picture box (bmp file)

Comment: @Brandon,can not convert integer to color  in "colors[x,y]=(Color)zz;"

Comment: Use Color.FromArgb(zz);

Comment: @Brandon,I use Color.FromArgb(zz) but picture not display,why?

Comment: I'm going to enter an answer because I've figured out what you're trying to do... hold on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast directly from integer to color. Using `Color.FromArgb()` allows you to specify an integer value for color.

`FromArgb()` takes a 32 bit integer where each byte represents one of Alpha, Red, Green, Blue (hence Argb). Keep in mind that if you want any pixel with more than half opacity (Alpha) value, your passed integer will need to be a negative value.

If you don't have any negative values in your Y1 array, you will want to apply the following when doing the `FromArgb()` conversion.

`colors[x,y]= Color.FromArgb(zz | (255 << 24))`

Hope that helps.

Comment: ,thanks for help me , I write "colors[x,y]= Color.FromArgb(zz | (255 << 24))",and show picture but Y1 represent brightness ,the picture must be gray but it display blue ??

Comment: You've altered the question since I answered, and with the information from your comment, I now have no idea what you're trying to do.