# the image not display in picture box

Tags: c#, .net, colors, picturebox, bmp

I write this code for display Y1(Brightness) in picture box:

```
R = new byte [width, height];// R,G,B not empty contain data

G = new byte [width, height];

B = new byte [width, height]; 

Y1 = new double[width, height];

Bitmap bmp4 = new Bitmap(width, height); 
Int32 zz; 

for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{

   Y1[x, y] = (0.39 * R[x,y]) + (0.59 * G[x,y]) + (0.12 * B[x,y]);

   zz = Convert.ToInt32(Y1[x, y]);

   bmp4.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(zz  ));
 }
```

when I execute this code picture box empty not display picture ,why??
this code in c# and type of image is bitmap

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974290/display-double-array-in-picturebox?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978085/convert-each-location-from-array-of-bytes-to-double?rq=1) and possibly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974290/display-double-array-in-picturebox?rq=1)

Comment: @venerik- though its douplicate but in those question there is no answer.. So this question is correct...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully had time to look at this, but the issue seems to be where you are converting the bytes to a color (setting each pixel to Color.Red, for example, works fine).

Of course, I am also assuming that you are calling this after your code:

```
picturebox.Image = bmp4;
```

**Color.FromArgb** expects the int32 to also contain alpha data, which I suspect is where your issue lies.